# How to connect laravel 5 to sql server database on ubuntu server ( nginx, PHP 7 installed)

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, nginx

My web application( laravel 4.2 ) is installed on ubuntu server, i am using nginx and php 5.4.

I am using FreeTDS to connect to sql server.

I want to migrate to PHP 7 and the latest version of laravel.

Is there another way like FreeTDS to connect to sql server with my new migration?